# Can I add users to www-data group in the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I want to add all of my admins to the www-data group so that we don't have trouble with file editing permissions (or having to set 777) when we are deploying Wordpress instances. Is it possible to add them to a group? I can't seem to get my own account pushed into www-data, even when I'm root.

Is it possible to add them all at once automatically every time we spin up a new server instance?

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to your issue on getting your own account pushed into www-data, but I think the command would look somewhat like this: `sudo useradd newuser1 --create-home --password "$(openssl passwd -1 "newuser1pass")" --shell /bin/bash --uid 5012 --user-group` - Aside from that, I have posted an answer about using startup scripts, check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) to set up the instance as you want.

If you are creating a custom scalable WordPress instance, you need to first create an Instance template and then create an [Instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances) of that template. To run the script whenever the instance from the instance group is created, when you are creating your Instance template, you must click on `Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy`. Then, under `Startup script (Optional)`, you will find a box to place your commands. Here you can add the script that will be executed in bash during every new launch of the instance.

If you are using the [`WordPress High Availability (BETA)` in Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress-ha?q=WordPress) to create your scalable instances, the solution is similar. The custom deployment will create the instance templates for you. You can select the Instance templates and click on `COPY`. Then you can add your script in the startup script section and save the new instance template. Then just create a new instance group using the new instance templates.

---

Additionally you can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638062/allowoverride-all-cloud-engine-template/52651143#52651143) that has more information on how to set up startup script in instance template for WordPress